# Represent the statement circuit as a picture.

Tags: logic

[image]

i would say the C is the answer. Correct?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Switches in series form an AND operation. Switches in parallel form an OR operation.

Comment: @ Ataraxia : so a is the answer

Comment: @MethodManX yes

Comment: thanks! i knew i was doing something wrong

Comment: @MethodManX No problem.